# Can #to_s ever fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, casting

I'm building a simple factory in Ruby that returns a `Callable` (a `Lambda` in this case) that knows how to cast to the passed type's name (e.g. `String.name # => 'String'`).

To attempt to cast `Fixnum`s I'm using `Integer` which will fail if the passed value is not convertable. Likewise I'm using `Float`, `Time.zone.parse(x).to_time`, etc...

For `String`s, however, I find myself simply using `#to_s` which, I believe, makes my `Lambda`s somewhat inconsistent because all but the `String` converter can fail (raise an `Exception`).

Assuming no malicious monkey patching, other than that provided by Rails, is it true that `#to_s` will never raise an exception?

Comment: From the [String.to_s documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-to_s): `Returns the receiver.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every object inherits from Object, which implements default `to_s` and `inspect`, returns "#" string. So if you will not override that definition, #to_s will work for every class.

However, one can write the own implementation of #to_s and raise the exception there, but it is unlikely - I can't imagine why should someone do that.

Comment: Actually you can inherit from BasicObject (which does not implement to_s)

Comment: Right! Anyway it is not very usual.

Answer (score 0):

Every object in Ruby inherits from the base Object which has a to_s implementation, so you should be ok. Keep in mind, the results can't always be predictable.

For example. nil.to_s returns ""

Comment: `nil.to_s` returning an empty string is completely predictable.

Comment: A poor choice of words. A lot of folks expect nil.to_s to return "nil" when it in fact returns "". To some this violates the principle of least surprise. We could argue all day about it, that's all I meant by my comment.

Comment: @JeffPrice Matz seems to prioritize convenience over predictability/consistency. `nil.to_s` returning `""` is much more useful than returning `"nil"`.

Comment: What else would it return? It returns the algebraic "zero" for every other class, so why would it return something different for strings? (I.e., for every `to_X` message that `nil` reponds to, the following holds true: `nil.to_X + some_X == some_X && some_X + nil.to_X == some_X`.)

Answer (score 0):

The `#to_X` methods (`to_a`, `to_h`, `to_s`, `to_f`, `to_i`, `to_c`, `to_r`) and the `to_XYZ` (`to_ary`, `to_hash`, `to_str`, `to_float`, `to_int`, `to_sym`, `to_proc`, `to_io`, `to_enum`, `to_path`) methods are not supposed to fail. An object may not respond to some or any of them, but if it *does* respond, then it shouldn't fail, it should not raise an exception and it should return an instance of the correct class.

I'm not sure if this is actually explicitly spelled out in the documentation, but that's how they are treated by the Ruby community.

The `Kernel#XYZ` methods (`Kernel#Array`, `Kernel#Complex`, `Kernel#Float`, `Kernel#Hash`, `Kernel#Integer`, `Kernel#Rational`, `Kernel#String`) OTOH will raise an exception if the argument is not convertible.

So, in short: *iff* an object responds to `to_s`, then it *shouldn't* fail, however, it may elect to simply not respond to `to_s` (which is highly unusual, though).